# How To Make The Divi Full Width Slider Responsive

Tags: wordpress, divi, divi-theme

Divi slider working fine on desktop but not looking good on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your Divi slider responsive we need to use Media Query add this CSS code in Customize option.

```
@media screen and (max-width:900px)
{
.et_pb_fullwidth_slider_0 .et_pb_slide {
background-size: contain!important;
height: 250px !important;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:479px)
{
.et_pb_fullwidth_slider_0 .et_pb_slide {
background-size: contain!important;
height: 110px !important;
}

}
```